# Checking for numbers and dashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a check on submit to validate some fields and I need to check for only numbers and dashes:

```
var numPattern = /^[0-9\-]+$/;
//UI field null check
if (ssn != (numPattern.test(ssn))) {
     displayError(Messages.ERR_TOPLEVEL);
}  
if (accntNoCL != (numPattern.test(accntNoCL))) {
    displayError(Messages.ERR_TOPLEVEL);
}
```

This is not working for some reason. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: "Is not working" means? Do you get an exception? Do you get unexpected results on certain inputs? Which inputs and which results?

Comment: `RegExp.test()` returns a boolean value.  Does that help you any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `regex.test()` function, or `numPattern.test()` in your case, returns a boolean `true`/`false` result.

In your code, `if (ssn != numPattern.test(ssn))`, you're checking if the result is equal to the value you're testing.

Try changing it to the following:

```
if (!numPattern.test(ssn)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`test` is a predicate, it returns a boolean:

```
var numPattern = /^[0-9\-]+$/;
numPattern.test("hello, world!"); // false
numPattern.test("123abc"); // false
numPattern.test("123"); // true
numPattern.test("12-3"); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

[`test`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) returns a boolean, not a match. Simply use

```
if (!numPattern.test(ssn)) {
    displayError(Messages.ERR_TOPLEVEL);
}  
if (!numPattern.test(accntNoCL)) {
    displayError(Messages.ERR_TOPLEVEL);
}
```

If you ever need a match, use either the [`match`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) function of strings or the [`exec`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp) function of regex objects.